# Pass angularjs value to PHP variable

Tags: php, angularjs

I am starting with angularjs with ngStorage. I can save and display data successfully.

I display value as before

```
{{myobj.session}}
```

I would like to pass whatever stored value into php variable. Shown below is my imaginary logic and I know thats not gonna work. My question is how to assign such value into PHP variable in a correct manner?

```
<?php 
    $name = {{myobj.session}}
?>
```

Comment: I believe you need to post it via AJAX

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am new to this technology. Can you show me how?

Comment: you can use `$http` service to pass data

Comment: Suggest you get a better understand of the difference between server side code and client side (browser) and various methods of communication between the 2

Answer (score 8):

You can use this angular variable: `students.tiffen_type`
PHP variable : `$value`

```
<?php
    $value = "{{ students.tiffen_type }}";
?>
```

Comment: I used this , and it works, but how ? it should not work at all. Angular is front code where as php is server code. Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: It works for me too. But please explain how it is working?

Comment: It take the value due to {{ }} in text

Answer (score 3):

You can do a ajax request like this:

```
$http({
        url: "urltopost.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data: variable
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

And on the backend you can get the variable like this

```
<?php
$request = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
$variable = $request->data
```

From there you can do everything you want with that variable, still I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I learned this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4vLTauq5j8 and everything is fine. But I couldn't assign outcome into PHP variable in php page.

Comment: You can't just assign the value to a php variable because once the page is loaded all the php is gone, php is server side code, in order to access / set php variables you have to communicate with the server via ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign directly angularjs value to php variable, use the following method it will help you

```js
     $http({
      method: "POST", 
      url: "test.php",  
      data: {
    data: postvariable 
      }
      }).success(function(response) {
           console.log(response); //get the echo value from php page
      }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
      });
```

test.php

```js
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo $data->data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

send.js

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "ajax/request.php",
    data: {
        angular_var: $scope.angular_var // $scope.angular_var is angular variable e.g. ng-model="angular_var"
    }, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

ajax/request.php

```
$request_arr = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
$angular_var = $request_arr->angular_var;
```