# Need to pass a angular js value into php function?

Tags: php, angularjs

I need to translate value thats why I wrote a function and I need to pass angular value into that php function.

> such as php function is

```
 <?php bn_translate(); ?>
```

> and angular js value is

```
 {{ result.min_tenure }}
```

> I tried this two ways but nothing changed

```
<?php print bn_translate("{{ result.min_tenure }}"); ?>
and
{{ <?php print bn_translate("result.min_tenure") }}; ?>
```

> or If I tried for test value that was successful translate

```
<?php print bn_translate("5"); ?> or <?php print bn_translate(5); ?>
```

Is it possible to pass value into php function to work properly?

Comment: use ajax to trans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass angularjs value to PHP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637243/pass-angularjs-value-to-php-variable)

Comment: You may want to use https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate instead of doing that on server

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs first, then angular js. As such your trying to pass a variable from the future (angular js) to a function that was called in the past (PHP).

You are essentially asking PHP to do the following:

```
<?php bn_translate("null"); ?>
```

The value in angular JS doesn't exist yet.

The only way to do what you want to do is send the variable via AJAX to a php script with the function.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an ajax call to pass values from frontend to backend, normally using a format like json. However, for something like translations you should try to avoid the roundtrip to your server, if possible. Good solutions would be using [angular-gettext](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext) or [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

**controller with injected $http**

```
$http({
    url: "script.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        data: result.min_tenure
    }
}).success(function(translated) {
    console.log(translated);
});
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
$request = json_decode( $_POST['data'] );
$text = $request->data
$translated = bn_translate($text)
echo (json_encode($text));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign value to the PHP variable and pass to php function

```
<?php
    $value = "{{ result.min_tenure }}";
?>
```